# How to import a script into .vue file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to import a player into my vue.js file. Normally I would use a script file outside of the template, but that does not work.

In an html file what I would do is the following:

```
 <div id="player">
    <div id="vplayer"></div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clappr@latest/dist/clappr.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  var urlsrc = "http://www.streambox.fr/playlists/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8";
  var player = new Clappr.Player({source: urlsrc, parentId: "#vplayer", height: 240, width: 320});
  </script>
```

In vue.js I am trying to do the same thing with the following return code, but it does not work:

```
     <template>
      <div id="player">
         <div id="vplayer"></div>
       </div>
     </template>

<script>

export default {

  name: 'player',
  data () {
    return {
      script: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clappr@latest/dist/clappr.min.js',
      url: 'http://www.streambox.fr/playlists/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8',
      player: new Clappr.Player({source: this.url, parentId: "#vplayer", height: 240, width: 320})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I get an error saying that the player is undefined. How can I get normal scripts to run inside of vue.js?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html). Make your own mixin and then add the methods from imported script inside methods section of mixin.

```
  var mixin = {
  methods: {
    foo: function () {
      console.log('foo')
    },
    conflicting: function () {
      console.log('from mixin')
    }
  }
}

var vm = new Vue({
  mixins: [mixin],
  methods: {
    bar: function () {
      console.log('bar')
    },
    conflicting: function () {
      console.log('from self')
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is adding external script in `created()` hooks and use script `onload` method

```
    <template>
      .... your HTML
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            url: 'http://www.streambox.fr/playlists/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8',
            player: null
        }),
        created() {
            let clapprScript = document.createElement('script')
            clapprScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clappr@latest/dist/clappr.min.js')
            clapprScript.onload = this.initPlayer;
            document.head.appendChild(clapprScript)
        },
        methods: {
            initPlayer() {
                this.player = new Clappr.Player({
                    source: this.url,
                    parentId: "#vplayer",
                    height: 240,
                    width: 320
                })
                console.log('Player is loaded')
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this, after installing Clappr with npm:

```
<script>
  import Clappr from 'clappr';
  export default {
      created() {
          let player = Clappr.Player({...});
      }
  }
</script>
```

This way you can initialize your clappr instance in the Vue component just as you would in vanilla html, js scenario.